# Shower Burnt out when not in use

Tags: electrical, shower

My Daughter has having a shower in her bathroom, at the opposite end of the house to ours. Our en-suite shower started making a dreadful banging noise and then water came out of the spray. It then started to smell really badly, I turned off the isolation switch and it stopped.
How could the shower that was not in use, turn on by itself and then burn out? The whole house smells of electrical fire

Comment: Could probably start taking everything apart, but having an electrician in to check everything might be a good idea.  It sounds like a short in the shower that your breakers did not respond to.  This is not good, your breakers should have tripped, before you had to act.

Comment: I'm going to go with "coincidence is not causation" regarding your daughter's shower happening to be at the same time your shower decided to fail dramatically.

Comment: Is there an in house water pump or boiler that supplies both of these showers? Is it accessible? If so, what does it look/smell like? Burning smell definitely means someone qualified should check and fix/replace, whatever it is.

Comment: Where on this planet are you?  you said you turned off the "isolation switch"  can you clarify what that is? Main Breaker?  What type of water heater(s) do you have? Any point of use water heaters?

Comment: Can you clarify: 'turn on by itself and then burn out'? The water turned on? I have no idea what 'burn out' means in the context of a shower.

Comment: peinal, my guess is that one or both of the showers have an in-line water heater.